# Three.js particle in front of camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a ParticleSystem and am trying to work out which particles are currently in front of the camera - ie in the frustum.

While I've had a look at [frustum.js](https://bitbucket.org/ayanami/three.js.git/src/9c8cbc39efbe/src/core/Frustum.js)  which has a handy function for determining if an object is in the frustum what's the method to determine if a single vertex is?

Comment: Maybe you can try with `Sprite`s instead?

Comment: I did have a go at that but was encountering performance issues. I have about 120k particles to be individually tracked. Maybe I wasn't handling sprites very well but I found that after a thousand or so, performance became a serious issue.

Comment: Ah, right... Yeah, that may require some special code then.